# Vbscript Trim function

Tags: vbscript, whitespace, space, trim, blank-line

I have a script that reads in a comma delimited text file, however whenever I use Trim(str) on one of the values I have extracted in the file, it won't work...

My Text File:

```
some string, anotherstring, onelaststring
some string, anotherstring, onelaststring
some string, anotherstring, onelaststring
some string, anotherstring, onelaststring
```

My Script:

```
Dim fso, myTxtFile
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set myTxtFile = fso.OpenTextFile("mytxt.txt")

Dim str, myTxtArr
txtContents myTxtFile.ReadAll
myTxtFile.close
myTxtArr = Split(txtContents, vbNewLine)

For each line in myTxtArr
    tLine = Split(tLine, ",")
    Trim(tLine(1))
    If tLine(1) = "anotherstring" Then
        MsgBox "match"
    End If
Next
```

My script never reaches "match" and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Are you getting an array out of bounds error?

Comment: No error, just does not trim

Comment: `trim("some string, anotherstring, onelaststring")` is never equal to `"anotherstring"`. Perhaps you want to split the lines on ","?

Comment: wow sorry I didn't include that part of my code, I updated it.

Comment: ahhhh. Okay. Makes so much sense.

Comment: `tLine = Split(tLine, ",")` ==> `tLine = Split(line, ",")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Trim()` is a function that returns the trimmed string. Your code uses it improperly. You need to use the returned value:

```
myTxtArr(1) = Trim(myTxtArr(1))
```

or use another variable to store the value, and use that separate variable in the comparison,

```
trimmedStr = Trim(myTxtArr(1))
If trimmedStr = "anotherstring" Then
```

or you can just use the function return value directly in the comparison,

```
If Trim(myTxtArr(1)) = "anotherstring" Then
```

Here's a corrected version of that portion of your code:

```
For each line in myTxtArr
    tLine = Split(line, ",")
    tLine(1) = Trim(tLine(1))
    If tLine(1) = "anotherstring" Then
        MsgBox "match"
    End If
Next
```

Comment: `tLine = Split(tLine, ",")` ==> `tLine = Split(line, ",")`

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner: Thanks. DIdn't see that error in the code I copied from the question. Thanks for pointing it out. Fixed.